# Components of a metric space are closed

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

[image]

$\\$
$\\$

Following is a proposition from Conway Complex Analysis. I am not able to prove part (a).

I know that if I have part (a), then part (b) follows by the fact that $C \subset \overline{C} \subset \overline{C} \,\,\,\, \implies \,\,\,\, \overline{C}\,\,\,$ is connected as $C$ is connected.

Now, as $C$ is maximal, $C=\overline{C}$, and thus $C$ is closed.

Notation:

$1. \,\,\, \subset$ is used to mean $\subseteq\\$

$2.$ A subset $C$ of a metric space is called a component if $C$ is a maximal connected subset of the metric space.

Comment: There is proof of this In munkres' topology book.

Comment: (a) holds in any topological space

Comment: Take a disconnection $\{U,V\}$ of $B$. Intersect with $A$. Draw conclusion. Use $B $ being a subset of the closure of $A$. Finish.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong. But I also encounter this question while I am studying Conway's Complex Analysis. Here is how I proceed with this question. I will try my best to draw every conclusion I used in the proof from Conway's book.

(a) Let $\bar{A}\subset X$ and $(\bar{A},d)$ a metric space whose metric inherited from $X$. Then $A\subset\bar{A}$ is connected since $(A,d)$ is a connected space and hence a connected subset of $\bar{A}$. $\textbf{Theorem 2.7}$ says that every metric space is a disjoint union of its components $C_j$ so that there must exist a $k$ such that $A\subset C_k$ since $A\cup C_k=C_k$ is connected by the lemma. In other words, we can find $B=C_k$ connected in $\bar{A}$ such that $A\subset B \subset\bar{A}$.

(b) We first claim that the closure of the connected set is connected. Suppose $C\subset X$ is connected and the closure $\bar{C}$ is not connected. Then $\bar{C}=A\cup B=\bar{A}\cup\bar{B}$ where $A,B$ are nonempty, open subsets in the metric space $(\bar{C},d)$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$. The first equality is due to the definition of disconnected set, and the second is because $\bar{\bar{C}}=\overline{A\cup B}=\bar{A}\cup\bar{B}$. Since $C\subset A\cup B$, we can write $C=(C\cap A)\cup(C\cap B)$. Since $A,B$ are open and $C\subset\bar{C}$, from the $\textbf{exercise 1.8}$, we know that $C\cap A$ and $C\cap B$ are open in $(C,d)$ and $(C\cap A)\cap(C\cap B)=\emptyset$. Also $C\cap A$ must be nonempty; otherwise, $C\subset B\subset\bar{B}$ implies $\bar{C}\subset\bar{B}$ and so $\bar{B}=\bar{C}$ but it also implies $\bar{A}=A=\emptyset$ which contradicts to our assumption. Hence $C\cap A$ is not empty, and so is $C \cap B$. But this contradicts to the fact that $C$ is connected, so $\bar{C}$ must be connected by contradiction. This establishes the claim.

Back to the question. Since $C$ is a component in $X$ so $C\subset\bar{C}\subset\bar{C}$ implies $\bar{C} = C$ and so $C$ is closed.